# Can a single letter be a palindrome?

Tags: palindrome

Is the word "I" a palindrome? What is the shortest palindrome?

Comment: The shortest palindrome would be a three-letter word like 'pop'. I suppose any single letter _could_ be regarded as one, but it's a bit pointless.

Comment: I agree, this is a pretty pointless question.

Comment: Seriously, what fork in what road depends on the answer? Is there a contest?  Can we all enter?

Comment: No, it isn't.  Trying to read 'I' as a palindrome introduces a catch 22.  You can't reach the end, because the start is the end.

Comment: Mathematically, yes, a single letter word is palindromic (also a zero-length word, but let's not get carried away just yet). But it just feels weird to reverse a single letter. So most people would not think of it as palindromic.

Comment: A type of lava, **aa**, has a palindromic name. It's the rough stuff, not pahoehoe, the smooth stuff. Single letters are the default case, and there's nothing gained or lost by calling them palindromes. There are not very many two letter palindromes.

Comment: To make an answer (despite this currently being closed), it helps to determine first what you mean by 'palindrome' (often with some motivated reasoning that makes the question work out the way you want). Here is a case where one can use mathematical principles to formulate a definition for a word. For 'palindrome' the definition should most likely be a word (or a string of letters) whose reverse is the same as itself. So then we have to define 'reverse' on strings. This is one of the classic first steps in recursive programming, mathematical induction and base cases.

Comment: I'm going to be a little technical here: suppose a string s is the first letter c followed by the rest of the string, rest(s). Then we can define the reverse of a string as the reverse of rest(s) followed by c (convince yourself of  the truth of this!). At each step of recursion, the string gets smaller by one character. It must stop at some point., when the length of rest(s) is too small. When to stop? we could choose 1 or 0 (a string of length zero is called the empty string. The reverse of a string of a single letter is that same letter.

Comment: Also, now we can define palindrome. It is a string whose reverse is itself. As just pointed out, the reverse of a single letter is that letter which fulfills that definition, a single letter is the reverse of itself. (or to be nit-picky, a string of a single letter is its own reverse (because reverse is defined on strings, not letters).Therefore, a word such as 'I' is technically a palindrome, b how we defined palindrome.

Comment: If for some reason a palindromic I bothers people so much, one would have to come up with a different definition. One could define the base case of 'reverse' to stop at -two- letters, but why would you do that because things work anyway if you stop at 1 (or 0).

Comment: What about the empty word? It vacuously satisfies the definition of a palindrome since it's the same when read backwards.

Comment: @JJJ Haha, empty word? I brought up the topic of the empty string, and from sources I've seen there seems to be an agreement that the empty string is a palindrome. Those sources were computer science/algorithm related. Either way in these cases, as in the case of math these seem to have formal definitions. Anyhow, what does an empty 'word' look like? Does it exist?

Comment: @Zebrafish in combinatorics we can compute the number of possible words of length n given a set of characters satisfying a rule (e.g. word reads the same when read backwards, none of the same characters next to each other in the word, etc.). We can use [generating functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2159771/142629) which always considered (unless excluded explicitly) one word of length zero. It's just one word and it's referred to as the empty word. It's like [the empty set being a subset of any other set (including the empty set)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/334876/142629).

Comment: @JJJ I see. That's one way "word" can be defined. But I assume the rules of the generating function have to include that characters generated of length 0 is a valid 'word' because the particular function is designed this way. If we created a function to output only English words, zero-length sequences would not be generated. So if we want to speak in terms of math or set theory I can understand the empty 'word'. I just don't understand what it means in our language, assuming words are made up of letters (written words I mean).

Comment: @Zebrafish I don't think there is a use for empty words in the English language (or other languages for that matter). It just happens to be useful in some counting problems. As such, it mostly stems from convention and it's not extremely weird to think about things having 'length' or 'distance' zero (whereas negative length is mostly unheard of). In the end, this question is probably more of a mathematics' one and the answer depends very much on the definition of a palindrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any official source for a technical definition of "palindrome" in the context of English, so you get to choose how you want to use the word.

I'm not sure why "the shortest palindrome" is an interesting question, but if you define "palindrome" to include single letters, then all single-letter* words would qualify as "the shortest palindromes" (in the English language). That includes not only *I* but also *a* and *O* and probably other more obscure words that I can't think of at the moment.

The technical definition of palindrome used in mathematics, when talking of "[palindromic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number)", does seem to include single-digit numbers, according to Wikipedia.

I just found a source that says basically the same thing as my second paragraph:

> Virtually any discussion of palindromes -- regardless of the source -- reveals a complete lack of interest in small words. In particular, one will rarely encounter a list of one-letter palindromes, presumably because that type of word **should be palindromic by any definition.**

Hall, T.A. (2011) "Not All One-letter Words Are Palindromes," *Word Ways*: Vol. 44 : Iss. 4 , Article 13. 
Available at: https://digitalcommons.butler.edu/wordways/vol44/iss4/13

---

*The issue of whether or not the empty string is a palindrome (which has been brought up in some comments) isn't relevant in the context of defining which English words are palindromes, because I think it's clear that the empty string (`""`) is not an English word.

Comment: If you look at the content of that article, it refers to a 'naive' understanding of -contractions-, some of which are also naively considered single letter words. I think the point is, contrary to the title, that those aren't words or not actually single letter words.

Comment: @Mitch: Hall says that contractions written with an apostrophe, like `'d`, are not palindromes, but he says that `I` (which is not written with an apostrophe) is a palindrome.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The only way that statement could make sense with respect to the title is if they consider "'d" a one-letter word.

Comment: I couldn't find an official source for a technical definition of "palindrome". I guess I learned there isn't one. Thank you @sumelic!

Answer (score 1):

Saying a single-letter is a palindrome is rather like saying 1 is prime because it can only be divided exactly by itself and 1 — but actually [it's not prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058414/primality-of-number-1).

The same holds of a palindrome: a single letter is a single letter; you can't read it in different directions, because once you have started you have come to the end. It's like a point: it has no direction.

There are two two-letter palindromes, though: [aa](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/aa) [oo](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/o-o). I don't count [ee](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ee) because it's merely an exclamation and could be spelled with any number of *E*s, including one. The others are pronounced as two separate letters because they're imported from Hawaiian.

Comment: Please provide a source for the assertion that a single letter is not a palindrome. Either definition is logically possible, and the definition that includes single characters seems to be the one used for [palindromic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_number).

Comment: @sumelic what is the simplest definition of "palindrome"? A word or sequence of words that read the same backwards as forwards. How does one read "I" backwards?? If "I" is part of a phrase then it's no longer a palindrome e.g. "I refer" becomes "Refer I" Not the same meaning.

Comment: @Mari-LouA However there is the classic palindrome "Able was I ere I saw Elba" where the pronouns are definitely read backwards and forwards. The word 'ere' is a palindrome in itself and it could be argued that 'I' is the same. The same argument could be made regarding the 'a' in the palindrome "Not a ton"

Comment: @BoldBen then "I" can be part of a palindrome phrase, just as "a" can be also used to construct a palindrome phrase, but neither "I" nor "a" can be read forwards or backwards, they're just one letter. You might as well argue that any number that is not flipped from 0 to 9 is a palindrome.

Comment: Andrew, the number 1 is considered 'not a prime' only for the convenience of base cases and simplicity of many theorems in number theory. If not for that, 1 holds most  (if not all) of the properties of primality. As to 'palindrome', [pretty much every one who thinks says a single letter is a palindrome](https://www.google.com/search?q=is+a+single+letter+a+palindrome). There are lots of concepts whose extreme cases are not labeled the same as the general case. For example people rarely would label themselves 'animal' even though it is technically the case.

Comment: On one hand it's true there's no direction in which to read, but if you take it from another point of view, I'm pretty sure most reverse functions with a single element or character as input would output that same thing. That's another way of looking at "reverse".

Comment: @Mitch Oooh, the empty string is a palindrome. That's.... interesting, and no doubt controversial.

Comment: Comments are not for discussion. If you want to discuss, get a room.

Comment: @Zebrafish Zero length is not controversial at all because it works (just like your single letter base case).

Comment: @AndrewLeach All these comments are relevant to the content of your answer.

Comment: @Mitch I mean as far as the ordinary English meaning goes it would be controversial. I've seen three sources saying that an empty string is a palindrome and they're all related to computer science or algorithms. I'm pretty sure there's no such thing as a zero-length character word in English, and palindromes are often defined as 'words' or 'phrases', which are the examples given here so far. We've already had 4 users here challenge that a single-letter word may be a palindrome. Something completely empty is likely to raise more disagreement, that's what I mean by controversial.

Comment: One can find mathematics books as late as the mid-20th century that include 1 in the list of primes. It is now universally excluded, but only as a matter of convenience. Many mathematical results (e.g., the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, a.k.a. the prime/unique factorization theorem) would require more cumbersome wording to remain valid. Much is gained by excluding 1 as a prime and the only thing lost is time needed to explain to mathematical novices why 1 is not prime.